# how to use hunspell (or other package maybe) to correct words using my own "dictionary"?

Tags: r, hunspell

I would like to correct some misspelled names based on another list, where the names are correct.

For example, I have this text:

```
ff Kazaroy, Sengir Pureblood S aE Didcono Ungido Ae yf Soldado do Bispo Ue ra Lamina Celeste daLegiao L
```

and I have this list:

Kazarov, Sengir Pureblood/
Diácono Ungido/
Soldado do Bispo/
Lâmina Celeste da Legião

I don't want hunspell to correct these words on my text based on the English dictionary, or any dictionary whatsoever (as Kazarov is a Russian name, some words are in English and others in Portuguese) so I'd rather used my list as a "dictionary". I tried adding custom words with add_words function.

I tried, as an example

```
text2 <- hunspell(text, dict = dictionary(add_words = "Kazarov, Sengir Pureblood")
print(text2[[1]])
hunspell_suggest(text2[[1]])
```

But not only it does not work but it still uses the English dictionary. I am considering creating a custom dictionary somehow, but I feel like it will not be very efficient (and I don't even know how to do it yet).

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is with:

```
dictionary(add_words = "Kazarov, Sengir Pureblood")
```

`add_words` should be a character vector.

Try:

```
dictionary(add_words = c("Kazarov", "Sengir", "Pureblood"))
```

It still looks like it has problems with Kazarov/Kazaroy, but the other 2 words go fine.